# Passando String entre classes

Tags: java, android

tenho minha classe principal onde tenho

...
String ola = "Olá amiguinhos";

e tenho minha outra classe:

```
public class NotificacaoDiaria extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "Funciona!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, ola, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Quero que essa string seja interpretada aqui, não para essa função, mas para que eu possa controlar ela nessa classe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei bem se é isso o quê você esta procurando:

## Na classe que você chama o BroadcastReceiver

```
Intent intent .....
intent.putExtra("label", String);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

## No BroadcastReceiver

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
   String teste = arg1.getStringExtra("teste"); 
   Toast.makeText(arg0, teste, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

> alteração forncecida pelo autor

Comment: na classe principal ta certinho, so no BroadcastReceiver que tiver que adptar:

public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
String teste = arg1.getStringExtra("teste");
Toast.makeText(arg0, teste, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}